# Othello game timer not working properly

Tags: java, timer, applet

I am just a beginner in Java. We have a college project and we are making a game called othello (also called reversi), we are using Java applet for the game. Board design and gameplay is complete and is working fine but we are having an issue with the timer.

The problem is player's move is not detected until timer has elapsed completely, i.e suppose timer for each move is 10 sec and if the user places his move at the 5th sec, his move will be detected only after 10 sec This behavior does not serve any purpose.

The method I am following is:

1. Display the time(integer) on the applet screen
2. Sleep for one sec
3. Increment time and update graphics

The whole thing is put inside the loop which is actually creating the problem. I need a better and in fact a working modification to this code.

Here are the code of two relevant functions

```
void startTimer() {

    Graphics g = getGraphics();

    for(sec =0 ; sec < 10 ; sec++){

        String time = new String();
        time = Integer.toString(sec);
        g.drawString(time, WIDTH+80, 145); 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        update(getGraphics());
    }
}


public boolean mouseUp(Event e, int x, int y) {


    int column = (int)(x / (WIDTH / 8));
    int row    = (int)(y / (WIDTH / 8));

    if (turn == BLACK) {
            if (placeLegalCheck(column, row, turn) == true){
                flipDisk(column, row, turn);
                turn = - turn;  
                diskCount();
                startTimer();
                update(getGraphics());


                try {
                  Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception excep){
                }
            }
    }

    if (turn == WHITE) {
            if (placeLegalCheck(column, row, turn) == true){
                flipDisk(column, row, turn);
                turn = - turn;  
                diskCount();
                startTimer();
                update(getGraphics());

                try {
                  Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception excep){
                }
            }
    }
return true;
}
```

Comment: `getGraphics` is not how you do custom painting. You should never call `update` manually, it's not your responsibility, use `repaint` instead. Applets are also deprecated and should probably avoid using them. I would take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). You should probably also take a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @MadProgrammer but can u please suggest a modification to this code itself...bcus i hv got only one day so cant change the entire framework..something like an if statement inside for loop which detects mouseUp event and breaks out...some soln please

Comment: Nope, won't work, you've approached the problem from the wrong direction and have fundamentally done the wrong thing, a "band-aid" won't fix this hemerage